# How to select items on <select> tags via Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: testing, xpath, scripting, automation, selenium-webdriver

Before posting this, I've thoroughly researched all possible syntax available for this and got no avail.

The closest I had was using this code where the dropdown actually appeared but didn't select my desired option:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")).sendKeys("Local Move"); 

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select"))).click();
```

I spent a significant amount of time today figuring this one out but I really failed on this one big time.

Comment: Try to use attributes like `id, class, name..etc` of a tag to avoid such long xpaths. This often causes your test case to fail, moreover shorter xpaths or selectors improve readability.

Comment: Maybe that answers my next question why sometimes my test case fails, sometimes it doesn't. Thank you! (Though I observed that sometimes, there's no ID nor Name attributes on some of the fields hence I strongly rely on xpaths. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")); 

Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);
Thread.sleep(5000L);
clickThis.selectByValue("1078");
```

It seems I needed Thread.sleep to let the system display the options completely before selenium can find the option I want for it to choose from.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To select a value from drop down. You need to use `Select` class from web driver.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")).sendKeys("Local Move");
```

Instead of the above line use this

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select"));
Select dropdown = new Select(ele);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Local Move");
// Can select the dropdown using `index` and `value`
dropdown.selectByValue("Local Move");
dropdown.selectByIndex("1234");
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that and had the same result with the ones I've tried before.

An error appears upon execution:

 - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element with text: Local Move

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` will throw if Web Driver not able to find the element in the DOM.You can use [`Explicit Wait`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-waits) + [`ExpectedConditions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and [`Implicit Wait`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) waits to pause the execution until the element present in DOM

Comment: I have recently solved this problem and I just used Thread.sleep to wait for the missing element to load completely. 

But during my research a while ago I've seen that 'Wait' / 'Fluent Wait' are more advisable to use than Thread.sleep due to some elements might load longer than the preset thread sleep

Answer (score 0):

To select a value from dropdown you should find the dropdown element by id then by value in the dropdown.

Try this:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdownid"))).selectByVisibleText("Text name");
```